# Is there a way to make a UserControl unfocussable?

Tags: .net, winforms

Is there a way to make a UserControl unfocussable?

EDIT:
So `SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false)`

is the way to go. But still there is difference to `Control`. If you inherit form `Control` the initial control does not lose focus. But after clicking on your control that is derived from `UserControl` and

```
ControlStyles.Selectable
```

is applied focus is removed from initial control.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your constructor after `InitializeComponent()` you need to call [`SetStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle.aspx) and set the [`ControlStyles.Selectable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle.aspx) style to `false`:

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
```

Comment: It does not work in case when UserControl has embedded TextBox. Text box will capture focus.

Comment: @volody: Yes, the child control can capture focus, but the `UserControl` cannot.

Comment: This does not work for me.

Answer (score 6):

Besides [ControlStyles.Selectable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle.aspx) there is also a [ControlStyles.ContainerControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle.aspx) - the documentation is rather sparse on this topic (*If true, the control is a container-like control*), but it somehow affects if the child controls get focus instead of the control itself.

**EDIT:**

I have just noticed another interesting fact. Viewing a UserControl in reflector shows that it forces setting the input focus in OnMouseDown. So overriding OnMouseDown without calling base.OnMouseDown(e) resolves the issue with no side-effects.

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.FocusInside())
    {
        this.FocusInternal();
    }
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
}
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer here which is working for me: Do not call base.OnMouseDown();

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the *SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);* works only if you are inheriting from a control.

It will not work, if you are inheriting from a user control.

To get around the problem, I added a panel to the user control and docked the panel to "Fill".
Added rest of the controls to the panel instead of the user control. It worked!

Comment: Adding a Panel is a clumsy and ugly workaround especially if you have many UserControl's where to do this!

Answer (score 1):

A UserControl, or any Control, will not be able to receive focus if the CanFocus property returns false.  If you look at the code in reflector it basically checks 3 properties and if any are false then it will be un-focusable.

- IsHandleCreated
- IsVisible
- IsEnabled

Setting the first two to false and having a functioning control is pretty much a contradiction.  If it's possible though for your control to be functional with IsEnabled being false then that should work.

Comment: Much easier to just set the ControlStyles.Selectable style to false.

Comment: If the control is disabled also all child controls will be disabled. This is mostly not what you want!

Answer (score 0):

Enabled = false, perhaps?

Comment: Focus is disabled ... But there are side effects like different behaviour of background images ... So nice try .. :)

Comment: If the control is disabled also all child controls will be disabled. This is mostly not what you want!

Answer (score 0):

You can get closer to what you want by setting [TabStop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabstop%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to false.  That'll prevent the control from getting focused when, for instance, a dialog-box above its owning form closes.

Comment: This does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from https://stackoverflow.com/users/1184950/tombam is the only correct one.

A `UserControl` sets focus to itself when processing its `MouseDown` event.

If the `UserControl` contains a selectable control then one of those is focused (not the `UserControl` itself). However, if the `UserControl` does not contain a selectable control then the `UserControl` itself receives focus. This happens even if you have done `SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);` - it will still receive focus when clicked.

The only way to stop this is to override the `OnMouseDown` method and not call the base method - as described in the answer referenced.

Of course, if you need the `MouseDown` event then you will have to reimplement your own as the base `UserControl.MouseDown` event will no longer be fired.