# How to prevent stealing focus when clicking on a usercontrol?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, focus

I want to be able to click on my user control and not have it steal focus from any other control.  I know when you click on a label it doesn't steal focus.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try disabling your control's [ControlStyles.Selectable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles.aspx) flag.

Comment: I just tried it in the constructor and OnLoad of my control and it didn't work: this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);

Comment: Google suggests http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785672/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-usercontrol-unfocussable